# If statement is not being registered prior to execution jQuery

Tags: jquery

I was unable to find anything relating specifically to this issue. I have a button to check the answer of the multiple choice question to check it is correct and if so it makes the next button active.

This is not the case though, even if none, or any radio button is selected it still executes.

EDIT UPDATE:This is now working. Thank you for all your input! Very much apppreciated!

```
next_test_section: function(test_id) {

    //VALIDATE  
    if($('#q1-a').is(':checked')) {
        var data = "test_id="+test_id+"&";

        async('get_test_data',data, function(response){
    /** Response success **/

            //$(this).parent().removeClass('has-error');

            $('.button-verify').val('Answer Correct');
            $('.button-next').attr('disabled', false);
            //alert($(':checked').val());
            $('.stage').html(response.html);
            user.update_progress_bar(40);

    }, function(response) {
        /** Response error **/

            //$(this).parent().addClass('has-error');
            if ($('.button-verify').val('Answer Incorrect', function() {
                $('.button-next').attr('disabled', true);
            }));

            //alert($(':checked').val());
            //alert('NEXT Error!!!')
            //<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="verify" value="Please answer correctly to proceed." />

        });

    }
},
```

HTML

```
                                    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab11">
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Question 1 is asked here.</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-9">
                                            <div class="radio">
                                                <label for="radio1">
                                                <input type="radio" id="q1-a" name="q1" value="option1"> Answer 1
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="radio">
                                                <label for="radio2">
                                                <input type="radio" id="q1-b" name="q1" value="option2"> Answer 2
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="radio">
                                                <label for="radio3">
                                                <input type="radio" id="q1-c" name="q1" value="option3"> Answer 3
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="radio">
                                                <label for="radio4">
                                                <input type="radio" id="q1-d" name="q1" value="option4"> Answer 4
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Any idea as to why this function proceeds even if I set the valid var to false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to check if the radio with the ID `#q1-a` is checked, and you'd do that like this

```
next_test_section: function(test_id) {
    if ( $('#q1-a').is(':checked') ) {
        var data = "test_id="+test_id+"&";

        async('get_test_data',data, function(response){

            $('.button-verify').val('Answer Correct');
            $('.button-next').prop('disabled', false);

            $('.stage').html(response.html);
            user.update_progress_bar(40);

        }, function(response) {

            $('.button-verify').val('Answer Incorrect');
            $('.button-next').prop('disabled', true);
        });
    }
},
```

`find()` only works on descendant elements, to check the current element use `is(':checked')`

Comment: I tried this prior and it didn't work I probably forgot something really stupid.

this is working.

Comment: I would kindly vote up but I do not have 15 reputation as of yet. Thank you for your input though.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
if($('#q1-a').find(':checked').length) var valid = true;

if(typeof(valid) === "boolean" && valid) { ..... }
```

Comment: @Ckracket updated my answer - maybe you need to check the type of `valid` because it is undefined when none is selected (you declare the variable only if you find any selected checkbox).

Comment: Yeah, its still not working even with your update. I'll play with it a little more see what I get.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable "valid" is not initiated for false value. try this:

```
var valid = false; 
if($('#q1-a').find(':checked')){
    valid = true; 
 }
```

and put all your code inside a jquery document Ready :(So, the code will run after the Jquery is ready.)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 /// all you function /// and running code.


});
```

Comment: This wouldn't work because all I am doing right now is throwing dummy data until the server is setup. 

This would work if `#q1-a` was a global answer. 

Thank you for your input.

Comment: use a click binding on your check box. when the check box is clicked. you check the value.. for #q-a, you have to write code for all of the id.